# Print render tree of webpage

Tags: html, css, dom, browser, web

I read that a 'render tree' is generated by a browser which combines HTML and CSS into a single tree.(Source: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction). Is there a way to actually print the render tree for a given webpage ?

Comment: When you say "print the render tree", what do you mean?  Are you looking for a textual representation of the tree? Do you want the DOM elements and all associated styles with them?

Comment: Yes. I want the Dom elements along with their styles

Answer (score 1):

I am in the search of the same capability as you! The closest thing that I´ve found is the DumpRenderTree tool that comes with the Webkit engine source.

[DumpRenderTree](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Tools/DumpRenderTree)
I haven't used it yet as I haven´t been able to compile webkit. But I´ve seen examples of it´s output:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
layer at (0,0) size 808x820
   RenderView at (0,0) size 800x600
   layer at (0,0) size 800x820
      RenderBlock {HTML} at (0,0) size 800x820
        RenderBody {BODY} at (8,8) size 784x804
         RenderHTMLCanvas {CANVAS} at (0,0) size 800x800 [bgcolor=#808080]
          RenderText {#text} at (0,0) size 0x0
    #EOF
#EOF
```

Yet this isn´t exactly what I need since it supposedly does not print ALL the styling information from an element

Hope this helps.